# Source code directories: "common" and "include"?

Tags: include, organization

I've noticed that some sources have *common* and/or *include* as sub-folders. I am talking about C/C++ sources in particular. What are they supposed to contain?

Comment: When you looked, what did you see?  Please provide examples on which you have **specific** questions.

Comment: It's quite different when looking at different sources. It looks like some have a "include" folder for shared header files, but then on others, the "common" folder seems to contain shared header files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the folder structure is consistent, either way is fine.  If the owner(s) of the source have both common and include folders, there should be an obvious distinction.  Hopefully these folders do not include other artifacts that should be somewhere else.

Are you having a particular problem?  or looking for a 'best practice'?  I usually think of an include folder to have .h/.hpp files whereas an common folder could contain images and other non .h/.hpp shared files.

Comment: This was a little helpful, thanks. Will wait for a more detailed explanation.